# jQuery/javascript DTD schema manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dtd

It's possible to load and parse DTD schema via javascript or jQuery ?
I know that jQuery is able to load XML file which has cross-browser support => and then manipulate with it via DOM Tree

But it's possible (some way) to do with DTD file too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it's possible. Check the [XML Validator at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

The function ValidateXML in the head of the page source will do what you want.

The input for the function is the XML file with a linked or embedded DTD, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE note [
  <!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
  <!ELEMENT to      (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT from    (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT body    (#PCDATA)>
]>
<note>
<to>Tove</to> 
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Reminder</heading> 
<message>Don't forget me this weekend!</message> 
</note>
```

Please note however, that w3schools.com has the following text on their "About Copyright" page, so you probably need to use the function to write your own variant.

> Pages, code or other content from W3Schools may not be redistributed
>   or reproduced in any way, shape, or form without the written
>   permission of Refsnes Data.

Comment: Coming here later: the W3Schools tool on that page does not appear to do XML validation, only well-formedness checking. The page makes that clear.